# mysql: getting primary key of a table programmatically

Tags: mysql

How can I get primary key of some table programmatically ? I know I can run some queries like "show create table" or "show keys" but after that I will have to parse the result for primary key. Was wondering if there was an easy way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

```
mysql> SHOW COLUMNS FROM foo WHERE `Key` = 'PRI';
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id    | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Now just read the names of your primary key column(s) in the `Field` column.

One weird aspect of this is that `Key` must be in back-ticks.  In spite of the fact that normally column names are case-insensitive in MySQL, it doesn't work unless you delimit `Key` in this case.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you're working with a "physical" table (i.e., not a view), you should be able to get a single string representation for the constituent columns of the primary key of a table, `foo.bar`, from the information_schema database:

```
mysql> SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('`', COLUMN_NAME, '`')) AS `PRIMARY KEY`
    -> FROM information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
    -> WHERE CONSTRAINT_NAME = 'PRIMARY'
    ->   AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'foo'
    ->   AND TABLE_NAME = 'bar'
    -> ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION;
+--------------+
| PRIMARY KEY  |
+--------------+
| `baz`,`zoid` |
+--------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Two caveats:

1. This may not work for other keys than primary
2. If you have very long column names or keys referencing very many columns, you may run into the GROUP_CONCAT cap:

   ```
   mysql> SELECT @@session.group_concat_max_len;
   +--------------------------------+
   | @@session.group_concat_max_len |
   +--------------------------------+
   |                           1024 |
   +--------------------------------+
   1 row in set (0.00 sec)
   ```

You can update this for the session, if needed, via the usual [set statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/set-statement.html).